# Update MySQL record using PHP/PDO dosn't work from w3schools

Tags: php

I have a problem with my code it stops working after I added update by id, i don't know where the problem is, i found many codes in the internet to update MySQL record but i found this the easeiar code i can get that's why i need help from you guys
The source from w3Schools
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";$username = "";$password = "";$dbname = "";
$id=$_GET['id'];

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT title, caption, url, main_image, ordering, state FROM slide WHERE id='$id'"); 
$stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
        foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $key=>$val)
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$title = $_POST["title"];
$caption = $_POST["caption"];
$sql = "UPDATE slide SET title='$title', caption='$caption' WHERE id='$id'";
// Prepare statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
// execute the query
$stmt->execute();
// echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
header("Location: edit.php?id=$id");
}  
}      
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

HTML Form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
<p><label>Title</label><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $val['title']; ?>"></p>
<p><label>caption</label><input type="text" name="caption" value="<?php echo $val['caption']; ?>"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="mySuccessFunction()"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: You have a try/catch block there, any error coming back?

Comment: @Steve the error log it's always empty

Comment: Please show us the function _mySuccessFunction_.

Comment: @dakis my problem resolved the answers below

Comment: Ok. Good luck further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using GET for the id but POST for the $title and $caption. They can't both be right.

Answer (score 0):

i just replaced

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
```

and i removed

```
action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"
```

from the form and i replace the submit name with save insted of submit